# set up a node to bake without having a roll of tezos?

Tags: baking

I do realize I would have to wait for people to delegate tezos to my network and reach the 8000 to actually bake on the network.

Is it possible to set up a node to bake without having a roll of tezos?
Or do I have to make that financial commitment upfront?

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement to set up a "node" in the network. A node's job is just to propagate actions of the network to other nodes. A node does not imply baking. A node operator is not given incentive (rewards) by the network to run a node. This fact is true throughout pretty much any other blockchain. Though if you want to bake, your baker software must communicate with a node.

As far as registering before having a full roll, while you may register your address as a baker at any time, you will not be given rights any earlier prior to accumulating a roll (8000 XTZ). So there is little reason to register as a baker before you have at least a roll (total of your own + people who delegate to you).

So to answer your question, yes, you will need at least a roll to bake.

Comment: Thank you Frank. 
I understand. 
How many tezos is it reasonable to expect to have delegated to a network.

Comment: One full roll is all you need. With one roll, you will be given rights to endorse or bake a couple times every cycle (~3 days).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can register as a baker in advance of having 8000 tez. Then you will have until the "Grace Period" cycle to perform successfully a baker action, such as bake or endorse. Happy baking!

Comment: Thank you. 
Can you elaborate on the grace period and endorsing  ?

Comment: @JonathanMangin https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html